# changing the format of a csv/excel file with headers in multiple rows

Tags: excel, csv, format

I have the following excel file which was a result of my code:
[image: Output I got from the code]

Is there a way I can merge the headers and its contents in the following manner?
[image: Desired format]

Comment: I'm dealing with a dictionary of dictionaries and data frame. It is leading to distorted content.

Comment: Are you asking how to fix your output, or how to get the correct output in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done with Power Query with just a few clicks.

- Promote first row as headers
- Filter to remove Heading_1 in the second column.

Done.